# Redirect share_ptr to point to another object

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

```
shared_ptr<int> ptr (new int(5));
ptr = new int(6); // this is illegal
```

How do I redirect ptr from an existing object(int 5) to another object?

Note that the implication is, ref count towards object int 5 should be decremented. and the ptr object should be pointing towards the new int 6 object after the intended "assignment".

Cheers.

Comment: Have you at least tried to look at the [interface of `std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)?

Comment: Prefer [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared): `auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>(5); ptr = std::make_shared<int>(6);`. It's more performant, easier to type - with `auto` that is - and harder to make mistakes with.

Answer (score 4):

The `shared_ptr` constructor from raw pointers is `explicit` to prevent accidentally taking ownership of pointers that should be owned (and should not be deleted). That means you cannot write:

```
shared_ptr<int> p = new int(5);
```

and instead you have to write:

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(5));
```

to call the explicit constructor explicitly.

For similar reasons, assignment from raw pointers is not supported either. You need to write either:

```
p = shared_ptr<int>(new int(6));
```

or:

```
p.reset(new int(6));
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple:

```
shared_ptr<int> ptr (new int(5));
ptr.reset(new int(6)); // this is legal
```

And still a clarification: the method .reset() decrements the reference count of the integer 5. So, if you check the program with Valgrind, it doesn't leak any memory.